# bit shifting in c returning wrong result

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, machine-code

I'm writing code to translate machine code. readFiveBytes is inside of a loop and supposed to take one byte at a time and place each byte into its correct place and return an address in the end.

```
void readFiveBytes(int c) {
    if (counter != 0) {
        currentIns = currentIns | (c << (counter * 4));
        printf("reading byte: %X; address: %08X; counter: %d; type: 5\n",c, currentIns, counter);
        counter = counter - 2;
    } else {
        currentIns = currentIns | c;
        printType3(currentIns);
        printf("reading byte: %X; address: %08X; counter: %d; type: 5\n",c, currentIns, counter);
        currentIns = 0x00000000000000;
        isFinishReading = true;
    }
}
```

the output is

```
reading byte: 71; address: 00000071; counter: 8; type: 5
reading byte: 26; address: 26000071; counter: 6; type: 5
reading byte: 0; address: 26000071; counter: 4; type: 5
reading byte: 0; address: 26000071; counter: 2; type: 5
reading byte: 0; address: 26000071; counter: 0; type: 5
```

I'm wondering why the first byte has not been shifted to the most left? (It seems like second one is working well)

Comment: what if `counter > CHAR_BIT`?

Comment: "bit shifting in c not working properly" – gotta love these "<core language feature X> not working" questions… surely it **is** working? At most *you* can't use it properly…

Comment: This type of function is the reason why people say that global variables are bad. This function doesn't even do anything by itself, it's the body of a loop that has been forcefully removed from its rightful place, and now communicates through some globals in a way that is not obvious and, from the looks of it, broken. Don't even fix this function, replace it by something better.

Comment: it is a great function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shifting the bit width or more is undefined behavior.

The first pass, `counter = 8` attempts `currentIns = currentIns | (c << 32);`.  Assuming `currentIns` is a 32-bit integer, this is undefined behavior.

The typical undefined behavior in this case is only a shift of `(counter * 4)%32` occurs.  With `counter = 8`, this is a shift of `0`.

Comment: currentIns's type is unsigned and unsigned int is 32 bit. That's why it is not working. Thank you!